# How to merge 2 batch commands result in one line

Tags: batch-file

I have below code in my file. Please help to get desired results.

```
for /f %%i in (D:\servers.txt) do ( echo Server_Name:%%i>>D:\log.txt & %systemroot%\System32\sc \\%%i query service |find "STATE"  >> D:\log.txt & echo ********************************************************************************* >>D:\log.txt)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Server_name:XYZ Status:running
***********************************
Server_name:PQR Status:running
***********************************
```

**What I am getting:**

```
Server_name:XYZ 
Status:running
*******************
Server_name:PQR
Status:running
*******************
```

Comment: Current Output:
Server_name:XYZ 
Status:running
*******************
Server_name:PQR
Status:running
*******************

Comment: Why not use a more appropriate methodology, WMI, instead, `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:@servers.txt /FailFast:On /User:UsersName /Password:UsersPwd /Output:log.txt Service Where Name="MySecretServiceName" Get State /Format:CSV`. Obviously adjust the `MySecretServiceName` to the name you've omitted from your question, and modify/remove the `/User` and `/Password` global switches as needed for your specific circumstances.

Comment: **The output you've stated that you're 'getting' is UNTRUE!** You're specifically `echo`ing `*********************************************************************************`, and telling us that its output is `*******************`, and you're also `echo`ing `Server_Name` and telling us that it's returning as `Server_name`!

Comment: Worse than that however is the second line must begin with spaces followed by something like `STATE              : 1  STOPPED` or `STATE              : 4  RUNNING`, because that is what `find "STATE"` must return. That means you're not only wanting to join two lines together, you're also looking for a way to modify the output from the second command too!

Comment: @Compo Hi Mate, Actually I am using this output in my .net code and need to put lot of logic to get required fields value. I am ok with spaces as I am using ":" as delimiter. Can we use pipeline ??